# webGL bindBuffer not working

Tags: javascript, webgl

While trying to display a few objects of different shapes in webgl, I found only the latest created buffer to be used while rendering. This seems odd since I bind the current buffer before rendering every time:

```
gl.useProgram(this.program);
gl.enableVertexAttribArray(this.a_Position);
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, this.buffer);

gl.uniformMatrix4fv(this.u_ModelMatrix, false, MVPMatrix.elements);
gl.uniform4fv(this.u_FragColor, this.color);

gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
gl.disableVertexAttribArray(this.a_Position);
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, null);
```

So to test the most basic example I tried to create two buffers after each other and see which one would be used:

```
var buffer = gl.createBuffer();
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer);
gl.enableVertexAttribArray(this.a_Position);
// gl.enableVertexAttribArray(this.a_UV);
gl.vertexAttribPointer(this.a_Position, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 3*4, 0);
// gl.vertexAttribPointer(this.a_UV, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 5*4, 3*4);
gl.bufferData(
    gl.ARRAY_BUFFER,
    new Float32Array([
         0.5,  0.5, 0,
        -0.5, -0.5, 0,
         0.5, -0.5, 0,
         0.5,  0.5, 0,
        -0.5,  0.5, 0,
        -0.5, -0.5, 0
    ]),
    gl.STATIC_DRAW
);
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, null);

var buffer2 = gl.createBuffer();
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer2);
gl.enableVertexAttribArray(this.a_Position);
gl.vertexAttribPointer(this.a_Position, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 3*4, 0);
gl.bufferData(
    gl.ARRAY_BUFFER,
    new Float32Array([
         1,  0.5, 0,
        -0, -0.5, 0,
         1, -0.5, 0,
         1,  0.5, 0,
        -0,  0.5, 0,
        -0, -0.5, 0
    ]),
   gl.STATIC_DRAW
);
this.buffer = buffer;
```

The result is that the latter buffer, (buffer2) is rendered every time. Why is that? What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vertex attribute pointers are a global state not local to buffers and there is no need to setup vertex attribute pointers for when you *set* data to a buffer.

A `vertexAttribPointer` call basically tells the GPU "hey the positions start at 0 and are 3 floats each" and the GPU obeys by setting the attribute *pointer* to `currently bound buffer address` + `attribute offset`, however when you change the buffer this pointer remains untouched still pointing at that "old" buffer, you need to update it by another call to `vertexAttribPointer`.

So your buffer initialization code becomes:

```
var buffer = gl.createBuffer();
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer);
gl.bufferData(
    gl.ARRAY_BUFFER,
    new Float32Array([
         0.5,  0.5, 0,
        -0.5, -0.5, 0,
         0.5, -0.5, 0,
         0.5,  0.5, 0,
        -0.5,  0.5, 0,
        -0.5, -0.5, 0
    ]),
    gl.STATIC_DRAW
);
```

In your render code you then set the vertex attribute pointers to the actively bound buffer:

```
gl.useProgram(this.program);
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, this.buffer);
gl.enableVertexAttribArray(this.a_Position);

// Set vertex attribute pointer to current buffer
// Note: I adjusted the stride to 0 to make sense
//       in the context of this question/answer
gl.vertexAttribPointer(this.a_Position, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

gl.uniformMatrix4fv(this.u_ModelMatrix, false, MVPMatrix.elements);
gl.uniform4fv(this.u_FragColor, this.color);
gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
```

Comment: Thanks! This differs a bit from OpenGL where vertexAttribPointer would be called at buffer creation? Also, setting the third argument in draw arrays to anything less than 6 won't render the whole square. 2 renders nothing and 3 renders half the square/a single triangle.

Comment: I dont think that it differs, maybe you're thinking about VAOs(Vertex Array Objects), these are [available in WebGL](http://blog.tojicode.com/2012/10/oesvertexarrayobject-extension.html) through an [extension](https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/extensions/OES_vertex_array_object/).
As to the index count on `drawArrays`, you're right, fixed that.

Comment: FYI if you want to use VAOs in WebGL 1 always [there's a polyfill for it](https://github.com/greggman/oes-vertex-array-object-polyfill) so I can just assume it's always there.